# array manipulations and extractions of data by names

Tags: arrays, r, data-manipulation

I need to manipulate my array.
I have an array call `res` which contain all my results. 
See just below the input.

```
    RT   Max    blk24  blk23    mat23   sm23    sm24
1   1.6  261    13     19       19      27      20
2   1.6  284    NA     53       5       99      91
3   1.7  304    NA     NA       NA      81      NA
4   1.8  305    32     28       28      39      33
5   1.9  322    8      NA       NA      36      39
6   1.9  349    NA     NA       NA      24      17
7   2    389    1       3       NA      50      NA
8   2.1  393    80      70      7       12      71
9   2.1  622    NA      NA      15      97      96
10  2.2  705    NA      NA      NA      NA      32
```

I want to extract my data according to the column name which are here `blk`, and `sm` and a criteria of the value by itself.

For `blk` I propose to do like that:

```
whereblk<- grep("^Blk", colnames(res))

for (i in 1:length(res)){
    tmp.res<-res[which(res[whereblk]>0),]
}
```

I get an output which give me all the `RT` and `Max` value when `blk>0`.

then I would like to extract the values from `sm` columns. I want to extract `sm` values when `blk=NA` and `mat=NA`.

do you have any clues ?

My desired output is :

```
    RT  Max         sm23    sm24
1   
2   
3   1.7 304         81      NA
4   
5   
6   1.9 349         24      17
7   
8   
9   
10  2.2 705         NA      32
```

To do it using excel, it is possible to use the followed formula, =IF(COUNTIF(blk:blk,">0"),"-",sm). The problem with excel is, I cannot use it automatically if for example the number of `blk` column changes.

The difficulty here is to use formula which localize the column position according to its name. And extract the value according to two criteria wich is something I still not master.

If you have any suggestion, you are very welcome.

Comment: Add the output of `dput(res)` so that others can recreate the array. Look into the command `subset` too.

Comment: It's really hard to tell exactly, but does `nams <- grepl("blk|mat", names(res)); res[rowSums(is.na(res[nams]))==sum(nams),]` do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dplyr solution.

I am fairly sure @thelatemail provided a solution that will work using just base R in the comments section.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "RT   Max    blk24  blk23    mat23   sm23    sm24
    1   1.6  261    13     19       19      27      20
    2   1.6  284    NA     53       5       99      91
    3   1.7  304    NA     NA       NA      81      NA
    4   1.8  305    32     28       28      39      33
    5   1.9  322    8      NA       NA      36      39
    6   1.9  349    NA     NA       NA      24      17
    7   2    389    1       3       NA      50      NA
    8   2.1  393    80      70      7       12      71
    9   2.1  622    NA      NA      15      97      96
    10  2.2  705    NA      NA      NA      NA      32", header = T)

nams <- df %>% select(matches('blk|mat')) 
df <- df[apply(nams, 1, function(i) all(is.na(i)))==TRUE,]

df

    RT Max blk24 blk23 mat23 sm23 sm24
3  1.7 304    NA    NA    NA   81   NA
6  1.9 349    NA    NA    NA   24   17
10 2.2 705    NA    NA    NA   NA   32
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` option with `Reduce` and `lapply` (assumption is that we have a `data.frame` or else convert to `data.frame` by `as.data.frame(m1)` - if it is a `matrix`)

```
nm1 <- grep("blk|mat", names(df), value = TRUE)
df[Reduce(`&`,lapply(df[nm1], is.na)), setdiff(names(df), nm1)]
#    RT Max sm23 sm24
#3  1.7 304   81   NA
#6  1.9 349   24   17
#10 2.2 705   NA   32
```

Comment: thank you I gonna make some documentation on Reduce function.